# Entity Framework Core foreign keys many

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-core

I'm using Entity Framework Core in context of a ASP.Net Core MVC application. A snippet of the data model looks like that:

```
public class Seminar
{       
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public Person Teacher { get; set; }
   public int TeacherID { get; set; }

   public IList<Person> Students { get; set; }

   public Seminar()
   {
      Students = new List<Person>();
   }
}
```

EF automatically assigns the property `TeacherID` to reflect the ID of the entity `Teacher` (foreign key). This is quite handy to be used in ASP.Net. Is there any similar concept for the to-many-reference `Students`?

At the end I would like to create a multi-select in ASP.Net. Hence, I need a list of IDs of assigned `Students` to this seminar.

Comment: If you mean something like `public IList<int> StudentIds { get; set; }`, no, EF does not support that. You can easily get the ids from the navigation property using LINQ `Select` though.

Comment: Yes. This was exactly what I ment. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

EF will infer the one-to-many relationship thanks to the `IList<Person> Students` navigation property, and it will refer to Students with that name. That is assuming that `Person` has a foreign key for `Seminar`. But then `Person` should also have a foreign key for seminar as a Teacher, so in the end that should be a many-to-many reationship, which requires a fluent API definition. Refer to this for more [info](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-ef-core.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by fluent api

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Seminars>()
.HasMany(c => c.Students)
.WithOptional()
.Map(m => m.MapKey("StudentId"));
```

Comment: This question relates to Entity Framework Core. .WithOptional() has been depreciated. in Entity Framework Core. Check out the Fluent API section of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/required-optional